# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, prediction, value = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, : replacement has 3462 rows, data has 1538

Tags: r

I am getting the above error in R when i try to predict and score the Pruned train tree on Testing data set

```
> dim(test)
[1] 1538   13

> test$prediction = predict(ptrain_tree, data = test, type="class")

**Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, prediction, value = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L,  : 
  replacement has 3462 rows, data has 1538**

> test$prob1 = predict(ptrain_tree, data = test, type = "prob" )[,"1"]

**Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, prob1, value = c(`1` = 0.004296875,  : 
  replacement has 3462 rows, data has 1538**
```

NOTE- ptrain_tree is my pruned tree created on train data set.

Comment: You need to post something reproducible here if you want help.  We don't have any of the variables you were using.  If you can't post the original data, make up a fake small dataset that has the same structure, see if it reproduces the same error, and if so, post that.

Comment: And show the R command for creating `ptrain_tree`.

Comment: My ptrain_tree code:                                                                                
minbucket = 10

train_tree <- rpart(formula = train$Personal.Loan ~ .,data = train, method = "class", control = r.ctrl)                                                                                                     ptrain_tree = prune(train_tree, cp= 0.001 ,"CP")

Comment: > names(train_tree)
 [1] "Age.in.years"        "Experience.in.years" "Income.in.K.month"   "ZIP.Code"           
 [5] "Family.members"      "CCAvg"               "Education"           "Mortgage"           
 [9] "Personal.Loan"       "Securities.Account"  "CD.Account"          "Online"             
[13] "CreditCard"

Comment: Is there is a way to attach files in this forum?

Comment: @AmitPanikulam please [check this on creating a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, use `dput()` to provide the data.

Answer (score 0):

The predict function for the test dataset is a bit tricky. It only works if you omit the `data=`.

Try: `test$prediction = predict(ptrain_tree, test, type="class")`

Comment: If this works for you, please mark this as the solution.